# error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

Following the syntax from the MySQL site on the MySQL C++ connector but not having good results, here is a snippet:

```
#include "/usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h"
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql_version.h"
#include "/usr/include/mysql_connection.h"
#include "/usr/include/mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace sql::mysql;
using namespace sql;


sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con;
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "db", "password");
sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt;
prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO db(srcIP, srcCountry, destIP, destHost, destPort, blIP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    prep_stmt->setString(1, src_ip);
    prep_stmt->setString(2, country_code);
    prep_stmt->setString(3, dest_ip);
    prep_stmt->setString(4, host_name);
    prep_stmt->setString(5, dest_prt);
    prep_stmt->setString(6, blip);
    prep_stmt->execute();

    delete prep_stmt;
    delete con;

            }
        else

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con;
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "db", "password");
sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO db(srcIP, srcCountry, destIP, destHost, destPort, blIP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    prep_stmt->setString(1, src_ip);
    prep_stmt->setString(2, country_code);
    prep_stmt->setString(3, dest_ip);
        prep_stmt->setString(4, he->h_name);
    prep_stmt->setString(5, dest_prt);
    prep_stmt->setString(6, blip);
    prep_stmt->execute();

    delete prep_stmt;
    delete con;
```

Compiling with:

g++ sql.c -o sql -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/cppconn -lmysqlcppconn -lmysql++ -lstdc++ -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient

and alway get the error on the second set of MySQL Driver:

error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Functions... your logic will typically reside in functions...

Comment: I am sorry, as I am new to programming (maybe a month) I don't feel confident enough to start answering questions.  I am sorry again but I am not exactly sure what the Functions comment is either.

Comment: I mean that you have asked questions (seven to be exact), but have not accepted a single response as the answer to any of them.  You should take a moment, go back, and accept those answers which solved your problem.

Comment: As for the "functions" comment, you have all of your code slapped into the file with no structure.  Your program will have an entry point (`main` for a typical console program) and from there you will perform your logic.

Comment: The compiler should be giving you a line number for this error. Assuming that it isn't massive it would make sense to paste all of the code for the function that the error resides in.

Comment: You should add `/usr/include/mysql` to your include path, usually the `-I` compiler option, to avoid having to specify full paths.

Comment: Thanks Ed S.  How do I accept a response as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based only on what I can see, it looks like you are missing braces around the statements you wish to be part of the else case. If you do this:

```
if (x)
{
   // do something
}
else
   Foo* foo = new foo();
   foo->someFunction();
```

You will get the error on the line which reads `foo->someFunction();` because the else contains only a single statement without braces and foo goes out of scope after that. You need to do this:

```
if (x)
{
   // do something
}
else
{
   Foo* foo = new foo();
   foo->someFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I knew that as well.  It reminds me of the movie Office Space when you forget the decimal!  I have been looking at it all day, sometimes it take an extra pair of eyes.